# Using SAS to insert rows containing nulls and blanks into database

Tags: insert, sas, db2

I have a db2 table `DBTable` with columns `A, B, C` (all of type varchar) which is linked to a library `lib` in SAS.
I use SAS to generate a dataset `ValuesForA` with one column whose content I want to write into the column `A` of `DBTable` with the additional requirement that the the column for `B` is filled with `' '` (blank) and the column for `C` with `(null)`. So the `DBTable` should look something like this:

```
|  A  |  B  |    C   |
======================
| 'x' | ' ' | (null) |
| 'y' | ' ' | (null) |
| 'z' | ' ' | (null) |
```

I cannot find a way how to acchieve this as SAS as it treats blanks as null.

---

The simple approach specifying `B` as `" "` just fills this column with `(null)`. I also tried to use the `nullchar=no` option and not specifying a value for `C`:

```
proc sql;
   insert into lib.DBTable
      (nullchar=no, A, B)
   select
       A, " " as B
   from ValuesForA;
quit;
```

however the column `C` is then also filled with blanks

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
===================
| 'x' | ' ' | ' ' |
| 'y' | ' ' | ' ' |
| 'z' | ' ' | ' ' |
```

Comment: Can you change the DB2 table to have column `B CHAR(whatever) DEFAULT ' '`

Comment: No, I can't. I don't have the rights for this. It's also part of a bigger project, so changes always have to be thought trough thoroughly. I just need this particular combination of data for testing some workflows.

Comment: You might need to copy ValuesForA  (just A,B) to a temp DB2 table with nullchar = no, and then submit sql passthrough to `insert into DBTable select * from temptable`

Comment: Since it is DB2 dba that created this mess by designing a table that wants to treat blank and null as different you should ask them to make a solution for you.  Perhaps they can make a writable view that does not include column C.

Comment: Problem is, that I cannot create temporary tables. It might also be bad design to distinguish between blank and (null) but it should be definitely doable to treat these logically very different pieces of information in different manners. So if this were not possible to do I, I would rather blame SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on [communities.sas.com](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Using-SAS-to-insert-rows-containing-nulls-and-blanks-into/m-p/647977).
In the end, I used a solution proposed by s_lassen (you may check out his other one).
I give my own description of his solution here:

It seems that inserting blanks and nulls is not possible over the linked libraies. We can, however, write a SAS-program that produces an sql-statement which we can execute on the database server itself using pass-through sql.

This is all done by this little script:

```
/* *** Create a temporary document with the name "tempsas" *** */
Filename tempsas temp;

/* *** Loop throuhg ValuesForA and write into tempsas. *** */
/* (The resulting tempsas is basically an SQL insert statement. All observations are written in one big values statement) */
Data _null_;
  file tempsas;
  set ValuesForA end=done;
  if _N_=1 then put
    'rsubmit;' /  
    'proc sql;' /
    '  Connect to DB2(<connect options>);'  /
    '  execute by DB2(' /
    '    insert into DBTable(A, B, C)' /
    '    values'
    ;
  put
    "       ('" a +(-1) "', ' ', null)" @;  /* "a" is an observation ValuesForA.a
                                               "+(-1)" removes the trailing blank set by the put statement
                                               "@" writes the next put statement in the same line */
  if done then put
     /
     '  );' /
     'quit;' /
     'endrsubmit;'
    ;
  else put ',';
run;

/* *** Run the code in tempsas *** */
%include tempsas;
```

It creates a file "tempsas" in which it writes and executes the following code:

```
rsubmit;
proc sql;
  Connect to DB2(<connect options>);
  execute by DB2(
    insert into DBTable(A, B, C)
    values
       ('x', ' ', null),
       ('y', ' ', null),
       ('z', ' ', null)
  );
quit;
endrsubmit;
```

I guess this solution is only feasible if there are not too many values to be inserted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
   insert into lib.DBTable
   select
       A, " " as B, null as C
   from ValuesForA;
quit;
```

This gave me the results you requested using a DB2 temp table with three VARCHAR columns.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. When I try this approach SAS interprets null as a variable and consequently reports that it could not find it in ValuesForA